# Bypass verification for GAS bound to a Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, authorization

Is it possible to bypass the verification process or at least the VERY SCARY "Go to  (unsafe)" in tiny letters next to "BACK TO SAFETY"?

I sometimes have a shared Google Sheet that is meant to be used by a volunteer organization (think neighborhood HOA or PTA, etc) and I add Apps Script to add menus to assist with adding or editing information on that Sheet only.  I don't request any user information and I'm not using the script to access the users Drive or Gmail or other sheets.

I haven't been able to find good documentation on this, but I can't tell if the Verification requirement stems from:

- The fact that there is a script running at all
- Some call I'm making to an API that is sensitive (and maybe I really am getting access that I don't realize?)
- Use of HTML forms

If it's the 2nd that could mean some changes could render my scripts harmless - Fyi a possible culprit is the use of SpreadsheetApp.  I use that to access .getActiveSheet(), .getActiveSpreadsheet(), .getUi().showModalDialog(), .Dimension.ROWS, .getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), .getUi()
    .createMenu()

Comment: The only way to remove that warning message is to go through the verification process.  There is no way to bypass that warning message.  You can find out what scopes your script is using by opening the script editor and navigate to File -> Project Properties -> Scopes tab.  There are many "sensitive" scopes.  The *restricted* scopes are for Drive and Gmail, but any sensitive scope requires verification.  The restricted scopes are listed in the documentation, but there is no list of sensitive scopes.  Showing a dialog box requires scope: **...googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui** =sensitive

Comment: I was afraid of that. I created a new question based on this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58454530) but do I need to publish it as a standalone Add-On to verify? The scripts are specific to their Sheets and can't be used in different formats.

Comment: The only way to apply for a script to be verified is to create a "standard" GCP project and associate it with that script.  Whether the Apps script project is bound or stand alone is immaterial to the verification.  There is an Apps Script **project**, which is the script, and there is a Google Cloud **Project.**  They both use the terminology "project" but they are two different things.  I think that it's possible to associate multiple Apps Script projects to one GCP project. But I'm not sure what the consequences of that are, or whether there is a limit.

Comment: If you could make your code generic, and have different configuration settings for different users, then you could avoid having lots of unique scripts.  Then you'd only need to verify one script.  If you created an add-on, then you could publish it, and your users could install the add-on, which would avoid the need to share files, or distribute files, and it keeps your code hidden.

Comment: If you skip the html dialog and your code could be restricted to run only on edit, It's pretty straightforward to use a simple `onEdit()` trigger to do the job.